# I have created a simple calculator program in python, the output seems to trouble me

Tags: python

```
# This function adds two numbers 
def add(x, y):
   return x + y

# This function subtracts two numbers 
def subtract(x, y):
   return x - y

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
   return x * y

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
   return x / y

print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")

# Take input from the user 
choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

if choice == '1':
   print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))
```

Hi,

Hi,
Hi, below is a simple python code for calculator, the output seems to be no as expected
  elif choice == '2':
       print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

```
elif choice == '3':
   print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))

elif choice == '4':
   print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))
else:
   print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: can you format your code and also tell us what is your output?

Answer (score 2):

The specific issue you're encountering is missing from your post, but running your code and entering integers along the way does indeed always land in the last `else` block and an "Invalid input" error message.

I'm guessing you're running Python 2, in which case the problem stems from the fact that you are comparing the value of `choice` to a string, but the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) function will return an int (if that's what the user typed in).

To solve this problem, you can either change your `if` blocks to compare `choice` with ints, or use the [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function, that will always return a string.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is `int(input("Enter first number: "))` the input is converted into an `int`, but you are comparing against `str` as `choice == '1'`.

Comment: Simple and precise answer .Thank you so much..was helpful

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct since `int(input("Enter first number: "))` is variable `num1` and not `choice`. The reason why choice is an int is explained in MaxyMoos answer.

Comment: Yes, @SitiSchu - you are right, I'd over looked
```
>>> input()
23
23
>>> raw_input()
123
'123'
>>>
 ```
+1 to MaxyMoos answer